# LookBehind Regex

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I am facing some trouble by creating a regex pattern in Python that will lookbehind & find some char.

Ex. x = " ? asdasdjkh khdsjkhas What???<!@#%^&*()ROOT"

in the above string ex. i am trying to find (double quote "). like the pattern start looking behind the ROOT & stop if it's find (" OR ' OR >) & print what it found.

Example Test:

x = `" ? asdasdjkh khdsjkhas What???<!@#%^&*()ROOT"`   ==> OUTPUT = `"`

x = `" ? asdasdjkh ' khdsjkhas What???<!@#%^&*()ROOT"` ==> OUTPUT = `'`

x = `" ? asdasdjkh > khdsjkhas What???<!@#%^&*()ROOT"` ==> OUTPUT = `>`

## ANOTHER EXAMPLE:

### Input

```
<select id="idAddCommune" name="idAddCommune"
data-rule-required="true"
data-msg="[Key delivery.pickup.front.select.commune.required.message Not Found]"
aria-required="true"
class="cform-control d-block-import idAddCommune"
onchange="selectCommune(this, 'HELLO? ROOT')" shippingGroup-id=""><option value="">Selecciona Comuna</option><option value="19">ARICA</option><option value="2023">BELEN</option><option value="2039">CAMARONES</option><option value="2046">CAQUENA</option><option value="2080">CODPA</option><option value="2092">COSAPILLA</option><option value="2107">CUYA</option><option value="2134">ESQUINA</option><option value="2137">GENERAL LAGOS</option><option value="2251">MOLINOS</option><option value="2272">PACHAMA</option><option value="2308">POCONCHILE</option><option value="2342">PUTRE</option><option value="2411">SOCOROMA</option><option value="2414">SORA</option><option value="2421">TIGNAMAR</option><option value="2447">VISVIRI</option></select><input type="hidden" value="" id="mapcityCommuneSelected" />
```

### Output

`'` because  if you search for ROOT keyword you will see it is inside the `' single quote`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done much easier using different logic: you want to match last occurence of one of characters from `'`, `"`, `>` before `ROOT`. So, I suggest such pattern: `['">](?=[^'">]*ROOT)`

Explanation:

`['">]` = match one of characters inside character class `'` or `"` or `>`

`(?=...)` - positive lookahead

`[^'">]*` - match zero or more of cany character other than `'` or `"` or `>`

`ROOT` - match `ROOT` literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hB9dP4/1)

Comment: @InjectorPca If answer has helped you, please acept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote, if you find it useful.

Comment: Is there is any chance we can find out if the reflection is in `JS` or in `HTML` like in the above ex. the reflection of `ROOT` is inside the `onchange` eventHandler or if there is any reflection of `ROOT` in `<script>` tags

Comment: @InjectorPca I think if you want to handle HTML, you have to use appropriate tool for that, like some HTML parser. Such opertions on HTML should not be done with regex.

Comment: I am afraid it is way too much logic for regex. You should break the problem down to little pieces and solve them with programming language you use.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need or want a lookbehind here.

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r"('|>|\")[^'\">]+?ROOT")
>>> p.search("foo ' bar ROOT").group(1)
"'"
>>> p.search('foo " bar ROOT').group(1)
'"'
>>> p.search("foo > bar ROOT").group(1)
'>'
```

Comment: Is there is any chance we can find out if the reflection is in `JS` or in `HTML` like in the above ex. the reflection of `ROOT` is inside the `onchange` eventHandler or if there is any reflection of `ROOT` in `<script>` tags

Comment: No. Parse the HTML in that case.